# Slide Up Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on trying to get a div to slide up from the bottom. So far it works ok as I can get the div to show and hide when I need to by adding a class of `open-drawer` to the element that I'm trying to get to slide up. But I'm not sure how I can get it to animate and slide up from the bottom.

Not sure if I need to adjust something within the `transition` or what.

Here's what I got so far:

```js
$(".drawer-link").click(function(e) {
  var vdata = $(this).data("id");
  $(".drawer[data-id=" + vdata + "]").addClass("open-drawer");
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(".close").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".drawer").removeClass("open-drawer");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #0c1f3f;
  padding-top: 90px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: top 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.open-drawer {
  top: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.close {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="drawer-link" href="#" data-id="drawer-01">Link To Show Drawer</a>
</div>

<div class="drawer" data-id="drawer-01">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <p>This is the drawer</p>
    <a class="close" href="#">Close The Drawer</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to demo (CodePen): https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/qzVQLp

Comment: Other answers offer valuable improvements. But in response to your existing code, give `.drawer` some initial `top` value from which to animate. For example, `top:100%`.

Comment: Also, since you're already using jQuery, consider the [`slideUp()`](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`slideDown()`](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) methods. Here's a [demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/hudaqs80/).

Comment: No, Don't use slideUp/Down(). Let CSS do the job for you.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I might agree in general, but the OP is already using jQuery, which provides the functionality. If you have a rationale that explains why not to use it, that might be good to mention.

Comment: @showdev  jQuery `animation` (slideUp / Down) does not uses `transform`. If it did I'd recommend it. And I would also not recommend to CSS-transition `top` or `bottom` properties either since not GPU accelerated.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The OP didn't mention any requirement to use `transform`. But I appreciate your response and your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three examples: **jQuery**, pure **JS**, and pure **HTML+CSS**

### Toggle animate panel using jQuery and [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

- Use `transform: translateY` at 100% and on click the class `.is-open` will  **animate to 0**.
- No need for extra special classes, use what you already have, a `data-*`
  attribute: `data-drawer="#drawer-01"`  (notice the ID `#` selector!)
- Also, make sure to use `id="drawer-01"` as the drawer selector.
- Use [jQuery's `.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Animating `transform` is always a better idea than animating non-accelerable  properties like `top`, `bottom` etc etc

```js
$("[data-drawer]").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).data("drawer")).toggleClass("is-open");
});
```

```css
.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #0c1f3f;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: white;
  
  /* Initial transforms */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.drawer.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#!" data-drawer="#drawer-01">Link To Show Drawer</a>
</div>

<div class="drawer" id="drawer-01">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <p>This is the drawer</p>
    <a data-drawer="#drawer-01" href="#!">Close The Drawer</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Toggle animate panel in pure JavaScript and [`.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

If you don't want to use jQuery only because of such a simple task, here's in *vanilla* JavaScript:

```js
const toggleDrawer = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector(evt.target.getAttribute('data-drawer')).classList.toggle('is-open');
}

document.querySelectorAll('[data-drawer]').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', toggleDrawer));
```

```css
.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #0c1f3f;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: white;
  
  /* Initial transforms */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.drawer.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<a href="#!" data-drawer="#drawer-01">Link To Show Drawer</a>

<div class="drawer" id="drawer-01">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <p>This is the drawer</p>
    <a data-drawer="#drawer-01" href="#!">Close The Drawer</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Toggle animate panel in pure HTML + CSS and a hidden checkbox

Need support for no-JS environment? Here you go

```css
.drawer-button {color: blue; cursor: pointer;}

.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #0c1f3f;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: white;
  
  /* Initial transforms */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.drawer-toggler:checked+.drawer {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<label class="drawer-button" for="drawer-01">SHOW DRAWER</label>

<div>Other HTML here...</div>

<input id="drawer-01" class="drawer-toggler" type="checkbox" hidden>
<div class="drawer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <p>This is the drawer</p>
    <label class="drawer-button" for="drawer-01">CLOSE DRAWER</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to give the `.drawer` a fixed height, then you can change the `bottom` property to initially be negative that amount.

Be sure to also add the opacity to the transition, otherwise it will instantly hide instead of fading out gently.

```js
$(".drawer-link").click(function(e) {
  var vdata = $(this).data("id");
  $(".drawer[data-id=" + vdata + "]").addClass("open-drawer");
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(".close").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".drawer").toggleClass("open-drawer");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.drawer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: -150px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #0c1f3f;
  padding-top: 90px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: bottom 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.open-drawer {
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.close {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="drawer-link" href="#" data-id="drawer-01">Link To Show Drawer</a>
</div>

<div class="drawer" data-id="drawer-01">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <p>This is the drawer</p>
    <a class="close" href="#">Close The Drawer</a>
  </div>
</div>
```